# Cannot retrieve value in DATETIME in mysql via PHP with a variable

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry guys Im new to stackoverflow - question section! I'm trying to query mysql db via PHP and I have ReqTime DATETIME on mysql DB.

```
//reqNo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,

$curDateTime =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$query4 = "INSERT INTO REQUEST(
            cNo, reqDate,ReqTime)
            VALUES(
            '$id','$curDate', '$curDateTime')";
```

However I'm trying to retrieve reqNo from REQUEST. But I don't get the value by following codes
    $query6 = "SELECT reqNo FROM REQUEST
                WHERE ReqTime = NOW()";
Neither by,

```
SELECT reqNo FROM REQUEST
WHERE ReqTime = \"'$curDateTime'\"";
```

Though when I try the following query I get the correct result.

```
SELECT reqNo FROM REQUEST
WHERE ReqTime = \"2013-09-21 08:02:33\" ;
```

Please help me to get the value by the following variable.

Comment: You should show some actual live code, and what happens when you run it.

Comment: Pay attention to case issues: in mySql "XX" is different from "xx", and you wrote it in these 2 ways in your question: they are actually two different tables.

Comment: The problem looks to be with the way you're quoting and interpolating the variable into your query. It's really hard to show how to fix it if you don't show the actual PHP statement. But it would be best if you didn't use variable interpolation at all. Use PDO or mysqlI and use prepared statements with placeholders.

Comment: If you want the current time, it would be better if you just use the MySQL function instead. `SELECT reqNo FROM REQUEST WHERE ReqTime = NOW()`

Comment: `cNo` and not `reqNo`? the more you edit your question the less consistent it gets...

Comment: Sorry guys Im new to stackoverflow - question section!

Comment: @AyeshaAmarasinghe you checked my answer?

Comment: For some reason your answer doesn't work Mansoorkhan. But thanx for the effort!

Comment: @AyeshaAmarasinghe, whats the error?

Comment: There were no errors I simply cannot get the value from the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$curDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "SELECT reqNo FROM REQUEST WHERE ReqTime = '".$curDateTime."'";
```